# Microsoft Project Online - Rest API Get Token

Tags: rest, sdk, office365api, project-online

I want to read projects and tasks from my Laravel application from Microsoft Project Online.

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a documentation on how to login/authenticate my users.

Users on my web app should be able to link their Microsoft Project Online site url, and authenticate to fetch their tasks.

How can I obtain a bearer token to execute REST api? Please lead me to a documentation that does so I'm lost.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408752/access-project-online-api-on-sharepoint-online-on-c-sharp